# Can't see hidden files with Standard user

Tags: terminal, finder, user-account, macos

I am using my Mac as a Standard user. Running latest OSX 10.10.3

I have used the following command from terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowALLFiles YES
```

But I still can't see my hidden files.

I've checked my ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist file and the correct entry is already there:

```
<dict>
    <key>AppleShowALLFiles</key>
    <string>YES</string>
```

If I login as Administrator, this command works fine. If I login as a different Standard user, this command works fine. It is something about this specific Standard user account that is preventing the command from working, but there is no way I am creating a new account just to fix this small issue. Anyone have any idea why this isn't working as it should?

Comment: while in the problematic user account try to repair disk permissions or even that users ACL's.

Comment: Ah, ok I googled `osx repair user permissions` and `osx repair user ACL` and found this link:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Apparently, a Disk Utility `Repair Disk Permissions` **does not** repair user directory permissions, or the ACL.  You have to follow a separate (and nonsensical) path to get to the utility that allows user permission repair.  I will try this and report back.

Comment: correct findings, and sorry for not been clearer, I newer know what the OP skills are.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> then open Terminal and type: `resetpassword`

On the next window, click on the name of your volume (usually “Macintosh HD”), then select the troubled user account name from the drop-down.

Skip the actual password fields (you are not changing the password).

Click the button on the bottom section labeled **“Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs.”**

Restart

Comment: It looks like this only works from Terminal if you boot into Recovery mode.  It does not work from the Terminal in OSX

Comment: I have not been able to reboot my computer yet.

Comment: A new problem ? Could you describe it?

Comment: No, I mean I have been too busy to shut down all my work and reboot my computer.  I will reply here as soon as I try the user permissions/ACL repair.

Comment: OK, I tried **Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs**.  For other people trying this, note that, you must boot into recovery mode *first*.  Also, if you are using File Vault (or if your disk is otherwise encrypted), after booting to recovery mode, you must *first* open Disk Utility and *unlock* the disk.  Only then can you quit Disk Utility and open Terminal (Utilities -> Terminal) and continue with the instructions.

Comment: Anyway, this didn't work.  I still can't view hidden files.  There is some other strangeness with my Standard user that I am just noticing now (I don't reboot my machine a lot).  *Every time* I reboot, my Mac *will not* let me into my Standard user.  it rejects my password (even though I am sure it is correct).  I must *first* login as the Administrator user (which takes longer than normal, displaying a progress bar for about 5 - 10 seconds), then log out, and only then can I login to my Standard user (the same password it rejected earlier works fine).  I can replicate this with every boot.